# Messaging library safe for client/server crashes?

Tags: zeromq, messaging, wamp-protocol

I'm evaluating some messaging libraries and protocols (e.g. ZeroMQ, WAMP). One of my main requirements is that sending messages from client to server and vice verse (two way communication) must be absolute safe with respect to client/server crashes. This means to me that e.g. the client must continue sending all not delivered messages after a spontaneous reboot. So the library should implement some kind of file based buffering. Is there anything there I can use out of the box?

[EDIT]
Some note on my use case:
In my scenario there are around 1000 clients communicating with one server. There is no direct client to client communication required. But I need a two-way communication, so both, the clients can push some data to the server and vice versa. The clients are connected via 3G mobile network. Both, client and server are written in C#. I focused on using ZeroMQ, Apache Thrift or WAMP. But one of the main requirements is to ensure asynchronous  but safe messaging with respect to system crashes. So when the client starts an asynchronous data push to the server, and it will crash before the message can be delivered to the server, it is required that the client will continue sending the message after a reboot.

Comment: Tell us more about your use case. Most tools/libraries are specialized, they do one thing very good, and are okish on the rest. From your post I don't get if you want something to abstract sockets (like 0MQ), of a full featured message queue (RabbitMQ etc)

Comment: You will have quite a lot of work to do to finally make your **`server`** and **`client`** processes achieve the level set as *(cit.)* **"must be absolute safe"**. Messaging will be just trivial once you manage this happen. Cool Project, anyway.

Comment: Many messaging libraries will provide you the *tools* to build the kind of safety you're looking for, but they won't provide it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the Apache.org's [Kafka project](https://kafka.apache.org/).

The problem is harder than it looks, and most people don't want to pay the price to make it happen.

Also, there is a UX issue with old queued up messages replaying without the user's understanding.